# Извлечение значения полей из вектора структур

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, структуры, вектор

Пытаюсь получить имена именованных каналов, открытых на текущий момент в системе. Объявляю вектор:

```
std::vector<FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION> pipesdata(4096);
```

Пытаюсь прочесть имена пайпов:

```
IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
BOOLEAN rec = TRUE;

while (1) {
  if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryDirectoryFile(
    pipes, // хэндл полученный CreateFile для \\.\\pipe\
    nullptr, nullptr, 0,
    &IoStatusBlock, // берем, но не читаем
    &pipesdata[0], // наши данные
    4096, 1, FALE, nullptr, rec
  ))) break;

  for (auto & pipe : pipesdata)
     std::wcout << pipe.FileName << std::endl;
  rec = FALSE;
}
```

В итоге получаю только названия не более двух пайпов. Правильно ли понимаю, что нужно имена пайпов извлекать относительно поля *NextEntryOffset* структуры FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION? Если да, то как к вектору можно применить эти смещения, в смысле получить адреса структур, а точнее извлечь из них поля *FileName*? Если несложно, объясните, что называется, на пальцах.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо размера буфера в байтах вы передаете количество элементов в нем.

```
static_cast<PVOID>(pipesdata.data()),
static_cast<ULONG>(pipesdata.size() * sizeof(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION))
```

При этом количество записанных байт будет записано в IoStatusBlock